# Нужно решить проблему с запаковкой прямоугольных объектов в сложный прямоугольник, заполнить площадь наибольшими прямоугольниками

Tags: python

Задача заключается в том что бы собрать «тетрис» из каталога прямоугольников определенных габаритов в один контейнер, есть что то общее с 2 d packing, подскажите какую библиотеку можно использовать на питоне.
[image: картинка для наглядности]

Comment: Попробуйте: PyRec, PyPack, PyBPA, PyGAPS. Думаю первый вариант(PyRec) вам подойдет лучше всего, но если нет, то попробуйте другие.